# "attachment for"?

Tags: word-usage

JavaLatte gave an excellent answer in 2017 about the verb attach, which takes the preposition "to". My question concerns **attachment** in a non-physical sense. "His attachment to his ex-girlfriend made him miserable for years." Here "to" feels too physical. I find myself preferring "for" when attachment is used in a mental/emotional sense: "His attachment **for** his ex finally ended when he fell in love with somebody else. Attached **to** her, he let go of his ex." For me, the to/for issue seems to concern the noun (attachment for), not the verb (attached to). Any thoughts?

Comment: The choice of preposition (which is essentially a matter of established idiomatic usage, not "grammatical rules") mainly depends on the preceding ***noun***. We normally use ***for*** after ***love, affection, feelings, passion*** and many similar terms, but ***to*** after others, such as ***attachment, devotion, loyalty,...***

Answer (score 1):

If it is the word "attachment" that sounds more physical in your context, you can use another word.

So, if you want to avoid this you can use a different word, like "affection for" or "passion for" - the solution to make it sound less physical is not in the preposition but in the word attachment /affection.

Comment: Your cited example *(**for** = for the **purpose** of...)* is a different usage to the one OP is asking about (***for*** as the preposition linking the two nouns ***attachment*** and ***his ex***; an alternative to the more usual ***to*** in such contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, so how does his suggestion "attachment for" sounds to you in his context? My point is that "attachment for" may not sound better than "attachment to" if the OP worries about how physically it sounds.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised to discover from [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attachment+to+his+wife%2Cattachment+for+his+wife&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattachment%20to%20his%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattachment%20for%20his%20wife%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cattachment%20to%20his%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattachment%20for%20his%20wife%3B%2Cc0) that *his attachment **for** his wife* did actually have at least *some* currency a century ago. But not today, when it's (almost) always ***to***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  NP, I edited my answer.

Comment: ...note that no native speaker would assume any kind of "physical" attachment, regardless of the preposition. So that's just a "non-issue".

Comment: I believe, it is the word "attachment," regardless of the preposition, that sounds physical to the OP, especially if he/she is a non-English speaker.